# Meteor - Passing helper parameters into pathFor call

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a helper, "route" that takes in the parameter "foo."

```
route:function(foo){
  If(foo == x){
      //Stuff
  }
  else{
      //Things
  }
}
```

This helper returns a dynamic key element of a route I need to create on the front end.  I want to format it like these, but neither works.

```
{{#each arrayOfThings}} <a href="{{pathFor 'path' _id=route "this" }}"></a> {{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each arrayOfThings}} <a href="{{pathFor 'path' _id={{route "this"}} }}"></a> {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested subexpressions can be wrapped in parenthesis to specify the order of evaluation, see [Spacebars Readme](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md). I have not tested it but would try:

```
{{#each arrayOfThings}} <a href="{{pathFor 'path' _id=(route "this") }}"></a> {{/each}}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That is perfect!  Thank you.